# Compute Module 4 board to board connector to OTG USB C

Tags: compute-module-4, otg

I am currently thinking about a project that I want to do with a Raspberry Pi CM4 or an equivalent product. The thing is that I know some things about Raspberry Pi computers (I own a 3B+ model) but in terms of their hardware, I don't really understand everything. What I would like to have is a very small computer (like the CM4) that can work on a single USB C port (like power delivery + display out + peripherals connection,etc). Can someone tell me if this would be possible with the CM4 or another product (if you could share me some links I would be grateful) ? Like can the board to board connectors be linked to a single OTG USB C port ?